# How to make magento core pagination as ajax pagination in a custom module

Tags: magento2.2, ajax, pagination

I am using **magento 2.2.2** and I want to implement **Ajax pagination** in my custom module. Magento has a pagination (getPagerHtml), but it's not implemented using Ajax, and I am trying to implement it using Ajax. But I am facing problem .
Any help please will be appreciated.

Comment: Please add code you have tried, it will be more helpful to answer

Comment: I am able to show  pagination on my storefront, when i click on next button or any other pagination button, it does not load collection because i don't know how to send Ajax request for Magento core pagination(getPagerHtml). So i just need help regarding Ajax request.

Comment: Take the reference to following extension https://github.com/czone-tech/magento2-ajaxified-catalog may be it' ll help you no your current development.

Comment: @EmiproTechnologiesPvt.Ltd. Thanks for your help, but it didn't work for me.

Comment: Please check this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/358191/82670